# Getting to Laulupidu – Estonia

Tags: public-transport, events, festivals, estonia, tallinn

I'm going to Laulupidu, the song and dance festival that happens every few years in Tallinn, and I want to know the best way to get to the festival grounds that Sunday from old city. It seems like it's walkable in a pinch, but I'm looking for shuttles or other public transportation.

Answer (score 5):

The festival grounds ([Lauluväljak](http://lauluvaljak.ee/en/info/area-map/)) is a bit out of the way but not very far (a little over 3km east of the old city). There are several [bus lines](http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/#bus/en) going past the festival grounds, including 1A, 8 and 34A from Virus Keskus and line 5 which goes through the old city, each with 2 to 4 buses per hour on Sunday. Some lines go to the Oru stop on the other side of the park.

The buses may be crowded — I don't see any indication of special event shuttles on the even web page.

There are events at the Kalev Central Stadium as well, which is near the long-distance bus station (Autobussijam) at the south-east of town, on tram line 2 and several local bus lines, and slightly under 2km from the old city.